# warning: passing argument 1 of 'setOn:' makes integer from pointer without a cast

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ios4

I'm new to Objective C so I apologize if this is a dumb question. I am getting this error in the following code.

I am using recurringBool as a Global Variable

```
//Declared in the AppDelegate.h
extern BOOL *recurringBool;

//Defined in the AppDelegate.m
BOOL *recurringBool;

// In another class this method sets recurringBool
- (IBAction)MakeRecurring:(id)sender {
    UISwitch *Switch = (UISwitch *)sender;
    //this is where the 1st error is occurring. aNetS is a UISwitch
    recurringBool = Switch.on;
        **//warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast**
}

//And in another method aNetS is set to recurringBool;
//this is where the second error is occurring. aNetS is a UISwitch
aNetS.on = recurringBool;
    //warning: passing argument 1 of 'setOn:' makes integer from pointer without a cast
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting these errors as recurringBool is not an integer. So I must assume that I am using it wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Remove the * from your BOOL declaration. A BOOL is not a pointer.

Comment: That was it! Sorry for the lame question I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Mark this answer as correct to help future readers, and to give Nathianal credit.

Answer (score 0):

`BOOL` is a primitive type, *not* an Objective-C object. You typically use it raw, like `int` or `float`, rather than via a pointer. So declare `BOOL recurringBool;` rather than `BOOL *recurringBool;`.